# What is the most efficient way to set multiple tkinter Menu items to "normal" all at once?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter Menu that looks something like the following, where root is my main Tk window, and f1,f2,g1,g2 are callback functions:

```
menubar = Menu(root)

menu1 = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="I do this", command=_f1)
menu1.entryconfig('I do this',state='disabled')

menu1.add_command(label="I do that", command=_f2)
menu1.entryconfig('I do that',state='disabled')
menubar.add_cascade(label='My to do list',menu=menu1)

menu2 = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu2.add_command(label="You do this", command=_g1)
menu2.entryconfig('You do this',state='disabled')

menu2.add_command(label="You do that", command=_g2)
menu2.entryconfig('You do that',state='disabled')
menubar.add_cascade(label='Your to do list',menu=menu2)

root.config(menu=menubar)
```

So there are two pull downs, `menu1` and `menu2`, each with two options. Currently the four options are disabled.

What is the most efficient means to set all four options to "normal?" I see how to do this for each pull down using simple list comprehension, but is there a way to do it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure multiple menu items at once. The `entryconfigure` method can only configure one thing at a time.

That being said, there are ways to iterate over all items in a menu. For example, here is a concise solution for enabling all items in two menus:

```
for menu in (menu1, menu2):
    for index in range(menu.index('end')+1):
        menu.entryconfigure(index, state="normal")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way. Looks like your best bet would be to do it one by one. Iterate through them if you like - it should save some typing time.